# VSCode IntelliSense autocomplete aliased imports

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm using alias on the `webpack.config.js` as:

```
const srcDir = join(__dirname, '..', 'src');
const webpackConfig = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "constants": `${srcDir}/constants",
```

And I have configured it on the `jsconfig.json` as:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "constants/*": ["./src/constants/*"],
```

My imports are in the format:

```
import CONSTANT from 'constants/constant';
```

It works for babel/webpack transpilation, but no for VSCode IntelliSense autocompletion.

I tried to play with the baseUrl and the paths, but no luck so far.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? I'm in the same situation right now.

Comment: Didn't found a solution. I remember I kind of made it good enough with some VSCode extension that used prediction, I think it was TabNine. Basically it would recommend a path once I wrote that path somewhere else in the codebase. Completely not ideal.

Comment: Best thing is to not rely on this aliasing mechanisms as often end up producing other issues like circular dependencies. Instead use relative paths, keep each project with low level nesting, and split into more packages using a monorepo if suitable. Consider that each package is an alias.

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks for the advice.